# Determine books currently under certification with ACL2

Tags: acl2

How do I see which books are currently being certified with ACL2 on a given machine?  I know I can look at the output and figure it out that, but that takes a non-trivial amount of effort.

Answer (score 0):

The following works on most systems:

```
ps axww | grep cert
```